# Deleting NAs in single plots [R]

Tags: r

I have a problem with deleting NAs in my R plot

I already tried [na.rm=TRUE] but they are still appearing in my plot.
Completely deleting the NAs out of my whole data set is not an option, because i would lose some important information, i only want to remove them for single plots.

```
barplot_B204 <- ggplot(ds, aes(x=B204), na.rm = TRUE)+
geom_bar()+
xlab("Partei")+
ylab("count")+
ggtitle("Welche Partei haben Sie mit Ihrer Zweitstimme bei der Bundestagswahl am 26.09.2021 gewählt?")

barplot_B204
```

Comment: `ggplot()` doesn't have a `na.rm` argument, but `geom_bar()` does. Try putting `na.rm = TRUE` there: `geom_bar(na.rm = TRUE)`. You can see the help pages `?ggplot` and `?geom_bar` to see what arguments each function takes.

Comment: Thank you, but i already tried putting it in geom_bar() and it didn`t work. Is there any other way?

Comment: Does `ggplot(filter(ds, !is.na(B204)), aes(x=B204)) + ...` not do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (temporarily) subset your data and then pass it to the ggplot.

**Base R:**

```r
library(ggplot2)
ds |>
    subset(!is.na(B204)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = B204)) +
    geom_bar()
```

**Full tidyverse:**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
ds |>
    drop_na(B204) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = B204)) +
    geom_bar()
```